# How do I copy a directory that has a date stamp

Tags: batch-file, directory, copy

I'm trying to copy the contents of a directory using a DOS batch file that begins with the computer name followed by an underscore and a date stamp. My first impulse was some variation of:

```
copy D:\%Computername%_\*\\*.* C:\WhateverPath
```

Of course I could not get this to work. Seems like a simple problem but I don't have much experience with batch files or DOS.

Comment: reason why this is not working is because you can not specify wildcards in the directory name, only in the filename.

Can you please specify if you have multiple folders with multiple timestamps? And do you wish for all the files within these folders to go into the same folder? Do you wish to have them moved into a folder with the same timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
FOR /d %d IN (D:\%COMPUTERNAME%_*) DO xcopy %d C:\WhateverPath /E
```

This iterates over all directories (hence the `/d`) with the pattern `%COMPUTERNAME%_*` under `D:\`, and copies the contents of these directories into `C:\WhateverPath`. `/E`is for copying all files and directories, also the empty ones.

For documentation of xcopy, type `xcopy /?` in a DOS shell (cmd).

**Note:** If you put this in a batch-file (something.bat), you must replace `%d` with `%%d` in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple folders labeled `C:\%computername%_%random_time_stamp%\` and you need to access each of them then move all of their contents to a single folder, you can do this:

Given the only underscore in the path is the one between %computername% and your timestamp

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F IN (`DIR /b /a:d "C:\" ^| FIND /I "%computername%_"`) DO (
 COPY /y "%%~fF\*" "C:\WhateverPath\"
)
```

That states for every result that comes from the command DIR, /b switch meaning no header information, /a:d meaning only returning directories, I want to find only folders with the computername_ in it, and I want to copy the contents of each of those folders to C:\WhateverPath\ folder.